# Java 21 vs Java 17 pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex, java-17, java-21

I'm currently trying to run a project with Java 21 which currently runs with Java17 without any problems.

For some of our regex patterns, there are matches with Java21 that did not match in Java17 and the other way around.

It is reproducible with this simle code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //english
        test(
                "...their sample variance, and σ2N their population variance.",
                "(?<![A-Z\\$€£¥฿฿=]-?[0-9\\.]{0,5})((\\b|\\-)[0-9]{1,5}[0-9,.]{0,5}(€|¥|฿|฿|°C|°F|°De?|°R[éeøa]?|(Z|E|P|T|G|M|k|h|da|d|c|m|µ|n|f|z|y)[ΩΩm]|[ΩΩ]|(Z|E|P|T|G|M|k|h|da|d|c|m|µ|n|p|f|a|z|y)?N|[kKMGTPEZY]i?B|[kmµnp]g|[Mk]t|kWh|GWa|MWd|MWh)(?!\\w))",
                true,
                null);
        //french
        test(
                "Il a été mis au banc de la société.",
                "\\bau (banc) (?:des nations|de la (?:société|ville|communauté|France)|de l['´‘’′](?:Europe|empire|église|islam))\\b",
                false,
                "au banc de la société");
    }

    private static void test(String text, String regex, boolean caseSensitive, String expected) {
        int flags = caseSensitive ? 0 : Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, flags);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int start = 0;
        String match = null;
        while (matcher.find(start)) {
            match = text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
            start = matcher.end();
        }
        System.out.println("Expected: " + expected);
        System.out.println("Got: " + match);
    }
```

Output with Java 17:

```
Expected: null
Got: null
Expected: au banc de la société
Got: au banc de la société
```

Output with Java 21:

```
Expected: null
Got: 2N
Expected: au banc de la société
Got: null
```

Expect the same behaviour in Java 21 like in Java 17.

Comment: You're using non-ASCII in your source files. Step 1 is to ensure encoding issues aren't to blame. __Triple check__ that your source files are saved as UTF_8 (this is a setting in your editor), and that you are compiling with `javac -encoding UTF-8 *.java` - or told maven or whatever you're using to do that. Failure of charset encoding lining up between editor and`javac` invocation can result in this, hence, why it's important to check. The edit question and reflect that you've eliminated that as an explanation.

Comment: Note also that your paste is just wrong. That cannot possibly result in the output you showed - your output starts with: "Expected: `null`" but your code passes the empty string. Therefore, what you pasted is not what you ran. Update that, too. Here's the thing: You're asking for something quite weird and more or less a bug in baked in APIs. 999 out of a 1000 cases it's pilot error.

Comment: maybe " Regex `\b` Character Class Now Matches ASCII Characters only by Default ([JDK-8264160](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8264160))"; less probable "Support Unicode 14.0 ([JDK-8268081](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8268081))" (both from Release Notes Java 19); or "Support Unicode 15.0 ([JDK-8284842](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8284842))" (Release Notes Java 20)

Comment: @rzwitserloot Everything is UTF-8 and I updated the code in this question regarding the null

Comment: BTW first test can be simplified to `test("σN", "\\bN", true, "found!")` and using `"(?U)\\bN"` avoids this discrepancy - confirming that it is related to `\b` and mentioned JDK-8264160  - no *time* to check second one

Comment: That would fully explain this, user85421. Upgrade that comment to an answer, I think :)

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Side note: you do not need to maintain a `start` variable. Just use `matcher.find()` to search from the end of the previous match (or the beginning on the first call). Further, `text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end())` can be simplified to `matcher.group()`. Just `while(matcher.find()) match = matcher.group();` This will record the last match, like your code.

Comment: This is just a simple code snipped to reproduce the issue because the original code base is much more complex.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> maybe " Regex \b Character Class Now Matches ASCII Characters only by Default (JDK-8264160)"; less probable "Support Unicode 14.0 (JDK-8268081)" (both from Release Notes Java 19); or "Support Unicode 15.0 (JDK-8284842)" (Release Notes Java 20) –
> user85421 2 days ago

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting (use code-formatting) where appropriate. If you cite and use the quote-formatting, also mention the source.